# How to copyclone a UIElement and keep the layout/render information?

Tags: c#, wpf, clone, uielement

I wish to copy a complex data-bound `UIElement` but keep the Binding, Layout and Rendering information from the original UIElement.

Creating a new `UIElement` seems inefficient since I would have to do another complete Binding/Measure/Arrange/Render pass.

The closest I've got so far is to create a new `DrawingVisual`, open it for rendering, and DrawDrawing using the source UIElement `DrawingGroup`.

```
DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingGroup dg = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(SourceElement);

using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
{
     Drawing d = dg.Children[0];
     dc.DrawDrawing(d);
}

return dv;
```

Is this a good approach and will it work for complex UIElements (e.g. lots of Panels within Borders, custom Controls etc etc)?

To give you a context, I am making a `DocumentPaginator` which is working well, but inefficeintly due to the recreation of identical UIElements.

Thanks in advance,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for presentation purposes, you can use a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx). More information can be found [here](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/05/15/wpf-visualbrush-basics/), [here](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/05/29/magnify), and [here](http://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/08/30/visual-brush-in-xaml/). It even reflects any live updates made to the attached visual.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I want to avoid the 'VisualBrush' for the very reason that it **does** reflect the changes to the attached visual. I want to be able to create a new 'UIElement' (or 'Visual') that uses the Source 'UIElement' info (time-taking layout and rendering info) to make an independent 'Visual' (that **does not** reflect changes to the SourceUIElement)