# How to show observable collection items on WPF canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, observablecollection

I have an observable collection which is binded to datagrid.
I can create wpf controls such as label,textbox etc into datagrid cells dynamically which in turn updates observable collection.

Now, I would like to show this collection of items on canvas in rows and columns as in datagrid.
Please help me to get that.
I am using the code as below.

```
ObservableCollection<Data> Items= this.Items as ObservableCollection<Data>;

              if (this.Items != null)
                    {                        
                        foreach (var element in this.Items)
                        {
                            if (element != null)
                            {
                                UIElement getitem = (UIElement)element.InputField;

             //where inputfield is a property which holds the control.                             
             // It eturns the control that has created.
                                canvas.Children.Add(getitem);//adding the control to canvas
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

But it throwing the exception(on adding the control to canvas) as below.
Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.

Thank you for your response.

Where Data is a class defined as below.

public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    private UIElement _uIElement; 
    public UIElement UIElement
    {
        get { return _uIElement; } 
        set 
        {
            if (value != _uIElement) 
            {
                _uIElement = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("UIElement"); 
            } 
        } 
    }

    private UIElement _inputField;
    public UIElement InputField 
    {
        get { return _inputField; } 
        set 
        {
            if (value != _inputField) 
            {
                _inputField = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("InputField"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name) 
    { 
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) 
        { 
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); 
        } 
    }
```

}
}

Inputfield and UIelement properties are the 2 columns of datagrid which holds the dynamic created controls information.

Answer (score 3):

A `Visual` can only have one parent so you would have to remove it from the `ObservableCollection` (which presumably your `DataGrid` is bound to) first....but then you would have it on your `Canvas` but not on your `DataGrid`.

So if you're trying to have 2 "views" of your collection of `UIElement`s at the same time, then you'd have to clone the elements so they could go into the `Canvas`.

What is the "Data" type...can you elaborate on it?

The preferred way to do things is keep your Model/View Models in the collection (not `UIElement`s), then define `DataTemplate`s which define the visuals for those data types. Then you can have the `DataGrid` and the `Canvas` both bind to the same collection of data, but they will each have their own inflated Visuals when the DataTemplates are applied.

See these links:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0df6181d-938f-4f45-9463-5b5035b57000/
- [How to copyclone a UIElement and keep the layout/render information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890298/how-to-copyclone-a-uielement-and-keep-the-layout-render-information)
- [Cloning WPF controls and object hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766787/cloning-wpf-controls-and-object-hierarchies)